# Why is this simple function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, variables

Why isn't this working? Similar code works here: http://www.ralphphillips.com/youtube/stick-figure/stick-figure2.html

But this isn't working. I have the html code correct. ID's are set but different Id's for each. It doesn't even give an output of 0 to indicate total is 0. No values show up.

```
<!-----SAMPLE INPUT ---->
<input type="radio" autocomplete="off" id="pack11049" name="radio-73" value="1"     
onkeyup="updateTotal()">


<script language="javascript">
function updateTotal() {

 var optionsPrice = 0;
 var accompPrice = 0;

function checkOptions() {       
if (document.getElementById('pack11049').checked) {
    optionsPrice += 1049;
    }

if (document.getElementById('pack21199').checked) {
    optionsPrice += 1199;
    }

if (document.getElementById('pack31199').checked) {
    optionsPrice += 1199;
    }

if (document.getElementById('pack41299').checked) {
    optionsPrice += 1299;
    }
if (document.getElementById('pack61499').checked) {
    optionsPrice += 1499;
    }
if (document.getElementById('pack71549').checked) {
    optionsPrice += 1549;
    }
if (document.getElementById('pack81699').checked) {
    optionsPrice += 1699;
    }
if (document.getElementById('pack91799').checked) {
    optionsPrice += 1799;
    }
if (document.getElementById('pack101999').checked) {
    optionsPrice += 1999;
    }
if (document.getElementById('pack112499').checked) {
    optionsPrice += 2499;
    }
if (document.getElementById('pack122549').checked) {
    optionsPrice += 2549;
    }
} // end of checking for Package


function checkAccomp() {

if (document.getElementById('howmany').value == '1') {
    accompPrice += 129;
    }

if (document.getElementById('howmany').value == '2') {
    accompPrice += 258;
    }

if (document.getElementById('howmany').value == '3') {
    accompPrice += 1057;
    }   

if (document.getElementById('howmany').value == '4') {
    accompPrice += 1856;
    }   

} // end of check accomp function

 checkPackage();
 checkAccomp();

 var totalPrice = optionsPrice + accompPrice;
 document.getElementById('optionsPrice').innerHTML = "$ " + optionsPrice;
 document.getElementById('accompPrice').innerHTML = "$ " + accompPrice;
 document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "$ " + totalPrice;


 } // end of my main update total function
 </script>
```

Comment: checkOptions and checkAccomp are defined within updateTotal for a start

Comment: In what way is it not working? What does happen? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Did you really mean to use the onkeyup event?

Comment: @Phil Mulkins: a Fiddle (jsfiddle.net) would be great in the future.

Comment: You don't need autocomplete="off" if the element is a radio button.

Comment: I would store that number data in the html, and then have only one function to change the optionsPrice.

Comment: First, throw some `alert`s in. Figure out exactly where it is 'not working'. Also, on a side note, You should give each input a class and make the code execute when any of the classes are changed. It would cut your code to like 10% of the length

Comment: Also the `language` attribute is deprecated and should be substituted with `type="text/javascript"` or `type="application/javascript`.

Comment: Definitely do try to stay away from that many `if` loops. Typically, if you have that many `if` loops, there's usually some way you can consolidate all of them into a single `for` loop using an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rewrite the `checkOptions` and `checkAccomp` functions and remove all these `if` statements using this pattern: create an object that stores the id of each checkbox and its corresponding price, and then use a `for-in` loop with key value lookup, like this:

```
var OptionPricing = {     

    'pack11049': 1049,
    'pack21199': 1199,
    'pack31199': 1199,
    'pack41299': 1299,
    'pack61499': 1499
};

var AccompPricing = {

    0: 0,
    1: 129,
    2: 258,
    3: 1057,
    4: 1856 
};

function checkOptions() {

    var Price = 0;

    for (Packs in OptionPricing) {

        if ($('#' + Packs).is(':checked')) {           
            Price += OptionPricing[Packs];
        }
    }

    return Price;
}

function checkAccomp() {

    var Accomp = parseInt($('#HowMany').val(), 10);

    return AccompPricing[Accomp];
}

function updateTotal() {

    var ThePrice = checkOptions() + checkAccomp();

    $('#TotalPrice').text(ThePrice);
}

$(function () { $('.DoPricing').click(updateTotal); });
```

**Here's the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BfJQQ/12/).** I didn't add all the ids and corresponding prices to the OptionPricing object but you get the idea. Also, if the prices change, or if new prices are added, this pattern should be easier to maintain, not to mention that the code is considerably reduced to just a few lines (and could even be reduced a bit further if you like terse syntax). I used jQuery (you had the tag in the question) but you could easily modify it and use plain js if needed.

Comment: This is more of what I need because the value has to be unique so I can identify the package on the php processing page. I will have more than one that has the same price. This works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: This is weird, I recreated the entire script you provided and it works fine on jsFiddle but when you select something on the page, it says the total is "NaN" no quotes, just NaN   .... any suggestions?

Comment: When I say Page, I mean on my wordpress page.php file.

Comment: Wait I found the problem! The HowMany Options form input values were not 1, 2,3 4. I previously changed them. The form now works Great! You are a rock star! Thank you again!

Comment: How would I add a dollar sign and the decimal point and two zeros on the end? Total Price: $1493.00  or Total Price: $1,493.00 with comma?

Comment: Comma may be too much. Just the $ sign and .00 would be great!

Comment: Got It! $('#TotalPrice').text('$' + ThePrice + '.00');

Comment: I have to add the total package price to the second selection of how many.  2: 258 + (var Price), How do you think I can write that?

Comment: Is there anyway to add the total price to the second occupant? 2: 258 represents Occupant #2 is being charged $258. But we also want to charge him the total price of package, so if there are 2 or more occupants, the price of the 1099 or 1999 for example needs to be added again starting and stopping at the #2 occupant. So 2: $258 + $1099 (OptionPricing which will change on selection)

Comment: Hi there, just got back online; I see you've been busy! I reread the last comment several times and I don't understand it. What are you trying to do??? What does "the second selection" mean?

Answer (score 1):

I would try this http://jsfiddle.net/EFWf5/1:

```js
$("form#order :input[type=radio]").each(function(){
    $(this).bind('change', function() {
        checkOptions();
    });
});

var checkOptions = function () {
    var total = 0;
    var pack = parseInt($('input[name=pack]:checked', '#order').val());
    var accomp = parseInt($('input[name=accomp]:checked', '#order').val());
    if (!isNaN(pack)) total += pack;
    if (!isNaN(accomp)) total += accomp;
    $('#total').text(total);
    $('#title').text($('input[name=pack]:checked', '#order').attr('title'));
};
```

```html
<form id="order">
    <div class="col">
        <strong>Package</strong><br /><hr />
        <input type="radio" name="pack" value="1049" />Pack 1<br />
        <input type="radio" name="pack" value="1199" title="MVP Package"/>Pack 2<br />
        <input type="radio" name="pack" value="1199" title="Oceanview" />Pack 3<br />
        <input type="radio" name="pack" value="1299" />Pack 4<br />
        <input type="radio" name="pack" value="1499" />Pack 5</div>
    <div class="col">
        <strong>Accomp</strong><br /><hr />
        <input type="radio" name="accomp" value="129" />1<br />
        <input type="radio" name="accomp" value="258" />2<br />
        <input type="radio" name="accomp" value="1057" />3<br />
        <input type="radio" name="accomp" value="1856" />4
    </div>
</form>
<div class="clear"></div>
<hr id="bar" />
<div class="clear"></div>
<div>
    <div class="col">
        <strong>Total: </strong><span id="total">0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="width:200px">
       <strong>Title: </strong><span id="title"></span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok here is 1 issue I have with this javascript. It works great, but I can't have the value be the same on any of the radio buttons because there will be more than one with the same price and I am using the value to identify each package so I can rewrite the price on the processing page. In other words, if (Pack == 1 then pack 1 = 1099 & pack title = MVP Package Price $1099)  if (pack == 2 then pack = 1099 & pack title = Oceanview Price $1099)

Comment: How would I identify between the packages if the 1099 is the only indicator?

Comment: The radio button name distinguishes the groups. Value is not an indicator.

Comment: If this helped you out, please feel free to press the up arrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I may be stating the obvious here, but the first function (updateTotal) is missing the closing brace. If you copied and pasted from your source then this might be your issue. Easy to overlook when you're staring at it ;-)