# Newbie needs some assistance

Tags: javascript

My code is this:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
var input;
var w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,w7,w8,w9,w10;
var w1 = ' ';
var w2 = ' ';
var w3 = ' ';
var w4 = ' ';
var w5 = ' ';
var w6 = ' ';
var w7 = ' ';
var w8 = ' ';
var w9 = ' ';
var w10 = ' ';

do {
    alert("Enter 10 words");
    w1 = prompt("Enter First Word", " ");
    w2 = prompt("Enter Second Word", " ");
    w3 = prompt("Enter Third Word", " ");
    w4 = prompt("Enter Fourth Word", " ");
    w5 = prompt("Enter Fifth Word", " ");
    w6 = prompt("Enter Sixth Word", " ");
    w7 = prompt("Enter Seventh Word", " ");
    w8 = prompt("Enter Eighth Word", " ");
    w9 = prompt("Enter Nineth Word", " ");
    w10 = prompt("Enter Tenth Word", " ");
} while(w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,w7,w8,w9,w10 == " ");

var myWords = new Array(10);
myWords[0] = w1;
myWords[1] = w2;
myWords[2] = w3;
myWords[3] = w4;
myWords[4] = w5;
myWords[5] = w6;
myWords[6] = w7;
myWords[7] = w8;
myWords[8] = w9;
myWords[9] = w10;

    for(i = 0; i < myWords.length; i++) {
        document.write(myWords[i] + "<br/>");
    } 
    document.write(myWords[0] + "<br/>");
    document.write(myWords[1] + " " + myWords[2] + "<br/>");
    document.write(myWords[3] + " " + myWords[4] + " " + myWords[5] + "<br/>");
    document.write(myWords[6] + " " + myWords[7] + " " + myWords[8] + " " +     myWords[9] + "<br/>");
</script>
```

How do can I change this to one prompt() instead of ten?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076429/why-is-this-simple-function-not-working Same concept, you could use an object with <key,value> to hold your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work for the prompt.

```
var words = prompt("Enter 10 words, separated by commas", "");
var array = words.split(" ");
```

There you have your array, then do your for loop or something :P

Comment: Sure, but what about the commas the user enters? You never remove them

Comment: This is closer. But some of the characters at the end are cut off.
 I just have to tweak it a bit.

Comment: So I took @ekreutz answer and added my for loops. So my finished product looks like this (and I realize document.write isn't supported by most...I just haven't been taught why yet).

 var words = prompt("Enter 10 words", "");
 var array = words.split(" ");

 for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  document.write(array[i] + "<br/>");
 } 
        //added my document.write tiers here. (I know, I know...sorry :) )
Works like a charm. Thanks again everyone for all your all help. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Keep the words in an array, and then use a for loop to prompt the user for each word.

```
var words = new Array(10);

alert("Enter " + words.length + " words");

for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = prompt("Enter Word " + (i + 1), " ");
}
```

Comment: I still remember when I first learnt about arrays – probably the youngest memory I have of suddenly seeing a world of opportunity ahead!

Comment: @Justin Thanks, it cleans up my script quite nicely, however, still not getting the desired prompt function I'm looking for. It might not even be possible. I basically need to put all ten words into one single prompt and then still have the tiered output in the browser.

Comment: @user2494640 see [NULL's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17157888/499214). The only incorrect part is where he doesn't tell you not to use `document.write`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myWords = [],
    word,
    thList = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Sixth', 'Seventh', 'Eighth', 'Nineth', 'Tenth'],
    i = 0,
    len = thList.length;

    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
        do {
            word = prompt("Enter " + thList[i] + " Word", " ");
        } while ( word == " " );
        myWords.push(word);
    }

// And then the document.write part
```

Comment: Can you suggest something else instead of `document.write`?

Comment: @JanDvorak I just copied the part from OP code... Just to indicate that all the above could be replaced.

Comment: ... no. A comment doesn't cut it. Please suggest a replacement.

Comment: @JanDvorak You are trying to answer another question then OP is asking.

Comment: Is your answer trying to conform OP's requirements, or to actually teach him something?

Comment: I'll be willing to upvote if you remove the last line entirely, and not acknowledge him using DW.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with `document.write` when used appropriately. It's just a tool. Nothing more. No need to freak out.

Comment: I like this edit. But, I think there was some confusion in my original post. I just need one prompt to put all ten words in.

Comment: @CrazyTrain `document.write` cannot be reasonably used on current-scope websites. 99% of all code runs after the page load. The only exception would be if you needed to load some javascript synchronously (in the "CDN with fallback" sense). Even for educational purposes, `innerHTML += ` is somewhat better.

Comment: @user2494640 in which case see [ekreutz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17157916/499214)...

Comment: @CrazyTrain note that I never downvoted the post. I just wanted NULL to not endorse DW before I upvote the rest.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I have no idea what you mean by "current-scope". Yes, it's handy for sync script loading, but I see to reason to go into a veritable panic mode just because you see `document.write` used in some other context. I disagree that `.innerHTML += ` is at all better. Once you use `document.write` incorrectly, you'll know it. When you use `.innerHTML` unwisely, the page will likely still appear to work, but problems may then manifest themselves in much more subtle ways.

Comment: @CrazyTrain actually, the best way would be to append `p`aragraphs to the body. Also, I agree `innerHTML` bugs might be subtler. But, at least `innerHTML` can be used asynchronously. A word of warning should be given. DW is easy to misuse (I do agree - if you do misuse it, you are sure to notice. But also, you are sure to not know how to fix it, and it can easily mask as other errors). IMO it's better not to teach DW at all.

Comment: @Ian I believe that's what CT means by saying "used incorrectly".

Comment: @JanDvorak I was just saying I think that was your point for your last comment, because most code runs **after** the `document` has closed, so we rarely have a reason to use `document.write`

Comment: @Ian: Yeah, I know. That's what I mean when I say the first time you use it incorrectly, you'll know it.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Absolutely, that's what I thought you meant when you said that. I guess I was trying to help explain what JanDvorak meant when mentioning "current-scope" and the related comment content. But I think you knew it all in the first place

Comment: @JanDvorak: I'd agree that a person shouldn't introduce it in an answer unless it's somehow especially relevant, which would seem rare. But in this case, OP is already using it, so an objecting to it isn't really on topic unless it was clear that it was being misused.

Comment: @CrazyTrain drive-by googlers don't read questions. To a drive-by googler, it might seem like you're endorsing DW. That's a reason enough why if you copy something incorrect from the asker, you should mention it's incorrect (or fix it). The asker benefits from you fixing it as well. Here, I'd suggest a footnote in the sense "DW will work here, but not in 90% of all cases you'll encounter. [Instead, consider using ...]"