# How to map strings to methods with a dictionary

Tags: c#

I have some code that looks like this:

```
switch(SomeString)
{
   case "Value1":
        MethodA();
        break;

   case "Value2":
        MethodB();
        break;
   ... 40 other cases
}
```

How could I rewrite this code using a dictionary of `<string, method>` so that for instance the key would be "Value1" and the value would be MethodA() and that I'd write something that says *"execute the function whose name is the value of key SomeString".* Note that all the methods take no argument and don't have any return.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+refactor+switch ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var actions = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
{
    { "Value1", () => MethodA() },
    { "Value2", () => MethodB() },
};
```

You would invoke like this:

```
actions["Value1"]();
```

Now you could simplify to this:

```
var actions = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
{
    { "Value1", MethodA },
    { "Value2", MethodB },
};
```

But I'd suggest going with the first option as it allows you to do this:

```
var hello = "Hello, World!";
var actions = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
{
    { "Value1", () => MethodA(42) },
    { "Value2", () => MethodB(hello) },
};
```

Comment: nice, just was thinking about delegates and lambda expressions.

Comment: +1. Side note: if following `() => MethodB(hello)` suggestion be very careful - C# captures variables, not the values - so if `hello` is ever changed call to `MethodB` will change too.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer; it's very similar in concept to this answer I wrote in javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076429/why-is-this-simple-function-not-working/17078580#17078580 Just didn't know how to make it work in C#! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Declare your dictionary:

`Dictionary<string,Action> methodMap = new Dictionary<string,Action>();;`

Add entries:

`methodMap["Value1"] = MethodA;`
...

Execute:

`methodMap["Value1"] ();`